# Analyze table V/s DBMS_STATS in Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Is `ANALYZE TABLE <table_name> COMPUTE/ESTIMATE STATISTICS` deprecated in Oracle 9i?

Though `DBMS_STATS` has an advantage over `ANALYZE`, can't I use `ANALYZE` in Oracle 9i? Won't it help me gather correct statistics?

Answer (score 2):

Please go through this link: http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/Tuning/TUNING_17.shtml

it describes the difference between ANALYZE and DBMS_STATS in section "Analyze vs. DBMS_STATS". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The ANALYZE creates histograms while DBMS_STATS collects more accurate statistics about the table. The cost based optimizer will decide on these, so it is useful to have better stat, so the optimizer might have better decisions.

Comment: I agree. But has it been deprecated in 9i? No, right? I can still use ANALYZE in 9i but with less advantage, right? I can't use it in 10g, I suppose.